# How to upgrade Rails applications without breaking anything?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I recently upgraded from Rails 3.1 to Rails 3.2. First, I had to fix some issues with [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise). Now I'm having this error:

> ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET]
>   "/javascripts/application.js"):

So I'm starting to wonder. How to upgrade Rails applications without breaking anything?

Comment: I followed this railscast and had no problems (my application is quite small): http://railscasts.com/episodes/318-upgrading-to-rails-3-2

Comment: Rails upgrades (usually only the big ones) sometimes include breaking changes. That's just the way things are

Comment: Your issue seems to be related to an ajax remote call, right ?

Comment: @aschuler I'm not sure. I get that error as soon as I start WEBrick.

Comment: If you use `<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>` you must have  this file there `/app/assets/javascripts/application.js`. This is related to rails 3.1 and the new assets pipeline. Further informations here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is always a chance that some gems could enter in conflict, especially if you upgrade as soon as a new version is released.

Personnaly, I check the changelog before upgrading, to see if something could be broken, and finally i only trust my unit tests.